# How to unbinde ajaxComplete() after a bootstrap modal was shown

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

First I create a person with a modal. If the first modal is submitted and the ajax is completed the second modal is displayed. But after that process if i click for example on a data table entry the second modal is displayed.

Here is the code when the second modal will be displayed:

```
        $("#submitModal").click(function() {
         $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {               
                    $('#secondModal').modal('show');
         });
         $("#submitModal").unbinde();
        });
```

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are having more problems after the removal of the event handler, you should update your question with more information and if possible a working example.

Answer (score 1):

The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().

The .click(handler) method is an alias for .on();

So your example will look like:

```
$("#submitModal").click(function() {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {               
        $('#secondModal').modal('show');
    });
    $("#submitModal").off('click');
});
```

Comment: `.click(...)` is a sugar for `.on('click', ...)` so you could've left the first line as is.

Comment: Thanks for your advices but my problem is still remaining. After the second modal is hidden and I click on any data table entry the second modal is displayed again.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Yes, but i think that one way to work with all the event attacher is better than multiple ones, after that if click will be calling .on in the background adding a little overhead, why not do it directly?

Comment: @ecarrizo I agree, but leaving as much code untouched mitigates confusion, especially if the reader doesn't know that there is no difference in using `.click` or `.on('click'`.

Comment: @Chris Can you provide a working example? Verify that the event is not fired after you call .off() (clicking #submitModal twice would be enough if you put console.log('clicked') at the begining. I think that your problem is that another elements are firing the modal 'show'.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak well you are right, i will try to no use my opinion in answers and change code if i will not providing corresponding information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submitModal").click(function()
```

can mybe can work in social bookmarking. i already crate and work on my site.
and then #submitmodal can be corectly

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Could you please try to rephrase?!

Comment: I usually find #submitModal iin social bookmark or other bookmark site